# Special elements of fields extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

I was wondering if there is a method to find all elements $w\in F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ such that $F(w)=F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, where $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are algebraic over the field $F$ of degrees $m_1,\ldots,m_n$, and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ are algebraically independent over $F$? 
This means that $B=\{\prod_{i=1}^{n}\alpha_{i}^{k_i}, 0\leq k_i\leq m_i-1 \text{ for all } 1\leq i \leq n\}$ is a basis of $F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$.

Would this be easier if $\gcd(m_1,\ldots,m_n)=1?$ Or if $\operatorname{char}(F)=0$?

Could you show this on a specific example, e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt[3]3)?$

Thank you.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Constructive_results

Comment: \gcd is a standard operatorn name.  I edited accordingly.  And added \operatorname{char}.

Comment: For infinite fields, it is known that $F(\alpha,\beta)=F(\alpha+c\beta)$ for all but finitely many $c\in K$.  I believe the proof of this fact is constructive in that it exhibits which $c$ cannot be chosen.  By induction, reducing from $2$ elements to $1$ gives a method to reduce from $n$ to $1$, although, this is not computationally friendly, nor is it exhaustive (it won't find *all* such primitive elements).  In the case of your example, we can take $c=1$ so that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt[3]{3})$ (Showing this fact is also computationally heavy).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly abstract answer:

Suppose we have found one primitive element $w$ with minimal polynomial $m(x) = x^n + \ldots \in F[x]$. Any element $y\in F(w)$ may be expressed as a rational polynomial of $w$ of degree at most $n-1$. Thus, if $F(y) = F(w)$ then $y = f(w)$ and $w = g(y)$. Hence, $w = (g\circ f)(w)$. Recall that we have an isomorphism,
$$
F(w) \cong F[x]/(m(x)).
$$

Then there is a correspondence between primitive elements and polynomials $h(x) \equiv x \bmod m(x)$ that decompose as $h = g\circ f$. The correspondence is certainly not one-to-one. However, I think the general intuition about when a polynomial decomposes as a composition is that its rare for both $g$ and $f$ to be non-linear. Hence, *most* other primitive roots come from composition with a linear factor.

Finding *some* primitive root is in practice not too difficult. I think *most* linear combinations of the $\alpha_i$ (as in your question) will result in primitive elements following an inductive argument like that suggested by Jared.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming characteristic zero, although this applies to a wide variety of positive characteristic situations too)

You're thinking about it backwards: nearly *every* element $w$ of $E = F(\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n)$ has the property that $F(w) = E$.

It's the elements $w$ such that $F(w) \neq E$ that are special. But there is an easy characterization:

- $F(w) \neq E$ if and only if $w$ is contained in an intermediate field $L \subsetneq E$.

So, if you can find all of the maximal subfields of $E$, then you have your description of the set of $w$'s such that $F(w) = E$: they are precisely the $w$'s that do not lie in any of those maximal subfields.

Comment: This strikes me as a bit weak, honestly.  Isn't the burden on you to enunciate the sense in which $E = F(w)$ is more typical?  For instance, I would like to say that viewing $E$ as an affine space over $F$, the set of $w \in E$ with $E = F(w)$ is nonempty and Zariski-open.  Is that correct?